# Why does my compositing screen look like a grid of quare shapes?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: blender composting screen]

Why does my Compositor preview look like a grid of quare shapes, when you get closer and further away these signs only change to others.

I tried to restart the computer and the Blender but everything remains the same, in new files everything is the same.

Comment: it looks like a bug, have you tried another Blender version, or with another graphic card driver?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)